Bad interaction between `\left` and `\begin{array}[b]`?
What's wrong with the following vertical brace?
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \left\{
    \begin{array}[b]{l}
      a = \\
      b = \\
      c =
    \end{array}
  \right.
  \overbrace{
    \begin{array}[b]{lll}
      u & v & w \\
      0 & 0 & 1 \\
      0 & 1 & 0 \\
      1 & 0 & 0
    \end{array}
  }^{control}
\end{equation}

\end{document}


Where does this extra vertical space come from?
How can I get rid of it?
(note: the \overbrace thing is not required to trigger the problem, it's just here for context)
(note: I would be glad to fix this without requiring extra package because the problem is currently blocking me in a constrained mathjax setting ^ ^")

see the delarray package in the core tools distribution

When you use \begin{array}[b], you switch the anchor point of the array to the lowest/last row. Then, when you add a brace, that brace necessarily has a centered (vertically) anchor point with equal length above and below to cover its contents. That's why you have a blank part below the array - the result of a symmetrical brace.
You can get away with a different layout, setting the construction inside a 2 x 2 array:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
  \begin{array}{ @{} c @{} c @{} }
    &
      \overbrace{
        \begin{array}{ c c c }
          u & v & w
        \end{array}
      }^{\text{control}} \\
    \left\{
      \begin{array}{ @{~} r @{} }
        a = \\ b = \\ c =
      \end{array}
    \right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace &
      \begin{array}{ @{} c c c @{} }
        \phantom{u} & \phantom{v} & \phantom{w} \\[-\normalbaselineskip]
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0
      \end{array}
  \end{array}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}

Some \phantom adjustments allow for column alignment within the second column.

You can use nicematrix:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

Let's check the vertical spacing above the matrix.
\[
\begin{NiceArray}{@{}c@{}>{{}}c<{{}}@{}ccc@{}}
  && \multicolumn{3}{c}{\text{control}} \\[0.6ex]
  &&  u & v & w \\
a &=& 0 & 0 & 1 \\
b &=& 0 & 1 & 0 \\
c &=& 1 & 9 & 0
\CodeAfter
  \OverBrace{2-3}{5-5}{}
  \SubMatrix\{{3-1}{5-5}.
\end{NiceArray}
\]
and also the vertical spacing below it.

\end{document}



Not sure I fully understand what you're trying to achieve. Maybe something like this?

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\text' macro
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{array}{@{}r@{}}
    \\
    \left\{
      \begin{array}{@{}r@{}}
        a = \\
        b = \\
        c =
      \end{array}
    \right.
    \end{array}
  \overbrace{
    \begin{array}{@{}ccc@{}}
      u & v & w \\
      0 & 0 & 1 \\
      0 & 1 & 0 \\
      1 & 0 & 0
    \end{array}
  }^{\text{control}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}


This does solve the problem, thank you. But it does not explain why there is extra space in the OP. Is this expected behaviour?

@iago-lito - The two [b] position specifiers don't work. (Not sure exactly why, to tell the truth.) Omit them. Once they're removed, you'll see that the first array (a 3x1 column vector flanked by an opening curly brace) is centered vertically relative to the second array (a 4x3 matrix). That's why I suggest encasing the \left\{ \begin{array}{@{}r@{}} a = \\ b = \\ c = \end{array} \right. construct in an additional array environment, to add an empty fourth row at the top. The @{} particles serve to suppress whitespace padding at the edges of the respective array environments.

Okay. Should I edit the OP to match your answer? Or wait for someone to also explain the problem with [b]?

@iago-lito - I'd recommend waiting and seeing if someone has the time, knowledge, and energy to post an in-depth analysis of why [b] doesn't work in the present context.
